# How to identify IP address on eth0 when the console isn’t available?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have very old Linux server with one IP address, unfortunately I can’t access Linux machine via console and I do not remember the IP address So now I'm thinking about a way that I could find this IP address. I'm not sure if it works but maybe by sniffer can check the server IP. 
I'm going to do the following:

- Download sniffer on my laptop
- Connect the laptop network to the linux machine VIA LAN cross cable ( END TO END )
- And try to run the sniffer in order to recognize the IP address from ETH0 ( Linux machines )

I'm thinking also about the option to build VB  script which scan the IP's from 1.1.1.1 to 255.255.255.255 - but this option is very difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [nmap](http://nmap.org/) to perform [host discovery](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html).

Comment: GUI tool for `nmap` is named `zenmap`. I also highly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the linux box makes connection to another server, look in that other servers MAC table. (`arp -a`. This will only work if there are connections or have been connections within the last 30 seconds. After this the ARP entry will expire).
2. If your very old Linux server uses DHCP to get that one IP address then look in the DHCP servers logs. Or, if you do not have access to that unplug the machine, connect it to a cheap SOHO router/access_point/WAP/switch and power on the linux machine.
3. If the linux box usually has network traffic then connect it to a managed switch. Log into the switch and let it show you which IPs and which MACs are in use.
4. Failing the above two options scan the whole network. Preferably after moving your scanning node and the Linux box to a separate switch as not to bother the rest of the network. [nmap](http://nmap.org/) (command line) or [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) (GUI for nmap) are the tools I usually use for this.

Lastly: If you have documentation then it should be in the docs. If not, add it to the docs.